# Issue resizing markers with Matplotlib and Jupyter Notebook

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter notebook to make a 3d plot, however the marker sizes will not change. I tried the code on both firefox (preferred) and on chrome. I also tried the different matplotlib dictionaries (widget and inline). I am on a linux machine if that helps. Can anyone help me here?

```
%matplotlib notebook
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = [0,1,2]
y = [4,3,2]
z = [5,3,4]
size = [1,20,100]
ax.scatter(x, y, z, size)
```

Comment: It''s `ax.scatter(x, y, z, s=size)`

Comment: Thank you for the help! I had tried using s=size yesterday and was getting an error of "too many arguments for s" but when I tried this today for some reason things are working. Thanks again!